# When to build routes and API spec with TSOA

Tags: tsoa

I am trying to implement TSOA with an existing HapiJS server and would like some insight on the best approach.

You can run `tsoa spec-and-routes` to generate `routes.ts` and `swagger.json`. However, running this manually before running the node process is less than ideal.

The solution would be then to run them programatically using the APIs provided by the TSOA library. However, when registering the routes with my Hapi server, I need to import the generated `routes.ts` file. e.g `import RegisterRoutes from '../build/routes.ts`.

So when I run the node process, generate the routes during this (programatically), it tries to grab '../build/routes.ts' before it has been built. Producing an error and the node proceess exits.

What is the way around this?

- `tsoa spec-and-routes && node bin/node` ?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.